Dynamic time axis in echarts
I have a classic line graph, where in my animation I want the x axis to unfold as the data goes along. I'm able to do this with gganimate and particularly view_follow().
However I'm switching my graphs to echarts4r and I can't find the option that can achieve that.
This is what I'm doing with gganimate.
tt<- structure(list(Season = c("2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024"), MM = structure(c(1672531200, 1672531200, 
1672531200, 1672531200, 1672531200, 1675209600, 1675209600, 1675209600, 
1675209600, 1675209600, 1677628800, 1677628800, 1677628800, 1677628800, 
1677628800, 1680307200, 1680307200, 1680307200, 1680307200, 1680307200
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), League = c("Bundesliga", 
"Liga", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Serie A", "Bundesliga", 
"Liga", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Serie A", "Bundesliga", 
"Liga", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Serie A", "Bundesliga", 
"Liga", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Serie A"), goals = c(70, 
102, 47, 66, 101, 102, 103, 97, 158, 139, 122, 92, 102, 115, 
76, 122, 3, 102, 29, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


graph2<- tt %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=MM, y=goals,color=League,group=League,label=League)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(vjust=0.5,hjust=0.5) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)+
  theme_ipsum()+
  theme(legend.position = "none") 
graph2

gxo<- options(gganimate.dev_args = list(width = 1920, height = 1080, units = 'px', res=320))

graph2.animation <- graph2 +
  transition_reveal(MM) + 
  view_follow(fixed_y = TRUE)

animate(graph2.animation, options= gxo, fps=60)

In echarts I've managed to get it right except for this dynamic time axis.
Here is my code:
tt %>% 
  group_by(League) %>% 
  e_charts(MM) %>%
  e_line(goals,symbol='none',smooth=TRUE,endLabel = list(show = TRUE, formatter = "{a}"))%>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>% 
  e_color(colrs) %>% 
  e_animation(duration=4500) 

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you for your help
